# Trouble declaring multiple functions below where

Tags: function, haskell

I'm having trouble declaring multiple functions after my initial function for `where`.

My function I am attempting to fix:

```
--initials function using where and pattern matching
initials :: String -> String -> String
initials firstname lastname = [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."
    where (f:_) = firstname
          (l:_) = lastname
```

I currently run the file in `ghci` by the command `:l functionSyntax` as the file is named `functionSyntax.hs`.

What am i doing wrong here? The site I am learning haskell from, [LearnYouaHaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards), has their code written as:

```
initials :: String -> String -> String  
initials firstname lastname = [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."  
    where (f:_) = firstname  
          (l:_) = lastname
```

which I feel is the exact same code, but I'm receiving the error:

```
ghci> :l functionSyntax
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( functionSyntax.hs, interpreted )

functionSyntax.hs:86:31: parse error on input `='
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I've tried looking up this error as it seems pretty common, but I can't seem to fix this seemingly simple problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Most likely an indentation issue with the `where` clause. The code runs fine on my machine. Which line is 86? As an aside, you should probably use `head`, which is a function which takes a list and returns the first element, instead of pattern matching the two arguements.

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces which is the most common problem for such cases.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code in a file called functionSyntax.hs, then I loaded the file into ghci just like you did, and your code works fine for me.

Comment: Why not simply `initials (f:_) (l:_) = [f] ++ ". " ++ [l] ++ "."` ?